# Avoiding scientific notation with Matlab

Tags: matlab, scientific-notation

I have altready tried:

```
format long g;
```

But a number like this shows with scientific notation:

```
ans = 8.80173259769825e-05
```

How can I avoid scientific notation without using something like `fprintf` ?

Comment: For such small numbers, I don't think you can. What's wrong with using `fprintf`?

Comment: You can always define something like `mydisp = @(x)fprintf('%8f', x)` and then call `mydisp(num)` without too much hassle.

Comment: llnk, so what would you want as an output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use:

```
sprintf('%.10f', yourNumber)
```

Or a more sophisticated option is to use Java-based formatting ([see more info](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) , credit to Yair Altman for showing this method), for example:

```
char(java.text.DecimalFormat('#.00000000').format(yourNumber));
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to:
Preferences > Command view > Numeric Format > bank

Comment: This is not an answer type either put it in comments or provide details in answer.

Comment: I don't see why this answer was downvoted. After searching everywhere and not finding an answer, this was the one that finally solved my problem.